# Scaled Parametrization of the Unit Square

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves, parametrization

Hi I am trying to find a parametrization of the unit square such that the domain in $t$ is in $[0,1]$.

I know that we can have a parametrization of the unit square like

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
      (0,t), t\in [0,1] \\ (t,1-t), t\in [0,1] \\ (1-t,1),t \in [0,1] \\ (0,1-t), t\in[0,1]
    \end{cases} \end{equation}

The curves are then joined to form the unit square. However I am looking for something like:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
      ... t \in [0,0.25] \\ ...t \in [0.25,0.5] \\ ...t \in [0.5,0.75]\\ ...t \in[0.75,1]
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

Is this possible by rescaling? I cannot find anything so far.

Comment: Replace t with 4t in your first form and restrict t to [0, 0.25]. In your second line of the first form then replace 4t with 4(t - 0.25) and restrict t to [0.25, 0.5]. And so on..

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I got it with your hint.

Answer (score 1):

So the parametrization given by works connecting the square with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$ in a counter-clockwise fashion for $t \in [0,1]$.

\begin{equation}
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
     (4t,0),t \in [0,0.25] \\ (1,4(t-0.25), t \in [0.25,0.5] \\(4(0.75-t),1), t \in [0.5,0.75]\\ (0,4(1-t), t \in[0.75,1]
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}